# Computing the $k$th iteration of the logistic map in one step

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Suppose we have the logistic map with parameter 4, that is take
$$
f(x) = 4x(1-x).
$$
For any point in $x_0 \in [0, 1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$, does there exists an equation I can use to compute $f^k(x_0)$ for any $k$?  That is, if $k$ is very large, say $10^{10}$, and I want to know $f^{10^{10}}(x_0)$, is there a way I can quickly compute that value?  The only way I know about is through iteration, or constructing the polynomial by taking $10^{10}$ compositions of $f$ (which gets you a polynomial of enormous degree).  Is there a faster way, and if not, is there some mathematical reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this parameter, and only for this, you can parametrize $x_0=\sin^2\theta_0$. Then it is easy to check that $$x_k=\sin^2(2^k\theta_0).$$ Now it remains to compute the reduced angle of $2^{10^{10}}\theta_0$ for the sine evaluation in sufficient accuracy, which requires to know $\pi$ with the same accuracy of about $3·10^9$ decimal digits.

Comment: Thanks!  How do we compute the reduced angle?  What is this computation (I am not sure what the reduced angle is)?

Comment: To compute the sine, the first step is to reduce the angle to the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ by periodicity and then a shorter one using symmetries and trigonometric identities. After that the value is computed using a uniformly accurate polynomial close to the Taylor series. Computing the correct multiple of $\pi$ is not problematic, reducing $\theta-m\pi$ is subject to catastrophic cancellation.

Comment: Library implementations simulate about 25 digits of $\pi$, so that mid-range arguments get a reliable result. With large angles you get floating point numbers where the distance to the next is larger than $1$, so that it is in doubt what angle these numbers represent.

Comment: Thanks for the response and helpful answer!  I ask the same question for the logistic map (linked below), perhaps you will be able to answer this one as well.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4550490/computing-the-kth-iteration-of-the-tent-map-in-one-step