# Computing the $k$th iteration of the tent map in one step

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Suppose we have the tent map, $T_\mu(x) = \mu \min(x, 1-x)$ with parameter $\mu = 2$ (so it is topologically conjugate to the logistic map with parameter $4$).

For any point $x_0 \in [0, 1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$, does there exist an equation/algorithm I can use to quickly compute $T_2^k(x_0)$ for any $k$ (especially when $k$ is very large)?  In the question [linked here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4550401/computing-the-kth-iteration-of-the-logistic-map-in-one-step), where I ask the same question for the logistic map, the answer is "yes, there does exist such a method."

However, because the tent-map is peicewise non-smooth and cannot be approximated well with any polynomial of relatively low degree (since we need to accurately simulate the steps of the map, which are sensitive to initial conditions), my thinking is that the answer in this case would be "no, there does not exist such a method", but I am unable to prove this.  Does anyone have a proof or argument otherwise?

Comment: If it's topologically conjugate to the logistic map then you can just use that topological conjugacy. The solution given to the linked question is, indeed, very sensitive to initial conditions, even if it looks like a closed form.

Comment: Here you get $\sin(\frac\pi2 x_{k+1})=\sin(\pi x_k)$. So setting $y_k=\sin^2(\frac\pi2 x_{k})$ you are back at the logistic map. More directly, one should get $x_k=\frac2\pi\arcsin(|\sin(2^{k-1}\pi x_0)|)$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks.  Do you know if there is a faster way to compute the $k$th point, or is there some "lower bound" on speed?  I want to compute a point that is $2^{100}$ iterations out, and so even using what you have said here or in the other answer, reducing $2^{2^{100}}\theta$ to the range $[-\pi, pi]$ is totally infeasible (unless there is some fast way to do that).

Comment: Here you can even say directly that every step loses you one bit of knowledge about $x_0$. So for a floating point input, after 53 steps, nothing of $x_0$ is left. Nothing interesting happens in the later steps.

Comment: @LutzLehmann and this is because the equations you give are approximations?  Or is it because the equations you give do not account for truncation in the "middle" iterations, so the result you get from using the equation is very different than the result obtained by iterating (with finite precision) after sufficiently many steps?

Comment: $\pi2^{k-1}x_0$ is from some point on an integer multiple of $\pi$ for any floating point number $x_0$. In the logistic map, the non-linearity acts as a pseudo-random number generator for the last bit. But in the tent map all operations are exact.