# Precisely computing nth iterate of tent map

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Suppose we have the tent map, $T_\mu(x) = \mu \min(x, 1-x)$ with parameter $\mu = 2$.

Then note that if we pick an $x_0 \in [0, 1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$, so that if $x_0 = p/q$ with $p, q$ co-prime and $q$ an odd integer, then the orbit $\mathcal{O}(x_0)$ under $T_2$ is necessarily periodic with the period bounded above by $\lceil q/2\rceil$.  In particular, all elements of the orbit $\mathcal{O}(x_0)$ are of form $a/q$, where after the first iteration $a$ is necessarily an even number.

This means that on a computer we can exactly compute such an orbit without a loss of precision.   My quesiton is, then, given such a setup, can one compute $T_2^n(x_0)$ in a single step without iterating (for any $n$), with the same perfect precision that you would get if you iterated?

If you see the related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4550490/computing-the-kth-iteration-of-the-tent-map-in-one-step), a commentor shows how you can compute $T^n_2(x_0) = x_n$ by
$$
x_n = \frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin (|\sin(2^{n-1}\pi x_0)|).
$$
But of course one can no longer compute this quantity with perfect precision as before.  So do we have a similar formula where in our special case with $\mu=2$ and $x_0 = p/q$ where we can explicitly compute $x_n$ without loss of precision?

Comment: I do not think that the contrast that you paint is as sharp as you imply. You do not have full accuracy in $x_0=p/q$. You could switch to the numerator iteration $p_{n+1}=2\min(p_n,q-p_n)$ which stays in the integers and has a finite range, so is or becomes periodic. But that only gives you an enumeration of the periodic sequence, not a formula. You might get a procedure, a finite automaton, that computes the result by parsing the bit sequence of the mantissa of the input number (without changing it), but that is not different than to perform the iteration $n$ times.